# angular 2 reactive form get input value without touched

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm  using **angular 5**, **reactive forms**. The problem is when I fill the input by value throw date-picker reactive form does not get value in "form Control Name" as flow.

**Screenshot**
[image: page screenshot]

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2  mb-2">
                  <label >From</label>
                  <input type="text"  id="fromDate" class="form-control "  placeholder="From Date" formControlName="fromDate" 
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':ifHasError('fromDate')}" >
                  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                      <span *ngIf="ifRequired('fromDate')">
                              {{ifRequired('fromDate')}}
                              </span>
                </div> 
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no form group added to your container. In order for formControlName to work the parent element must have [fromGroup]="myForm" and in your component you would need to define myForm like this:

```
myForm: FromGroup();
constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder
){
  this.myForm = fb.group({
     fromDate: ["", Validators.required]
  })
}
```

in your template

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input formControlName="fromDate" placeholder="From Date" type="date" />
</div>
```

Comment: that is not a problem, i have FromGroup, formControlName  get a value when i right it but if i set input text value without touch input formControlName  does not take a value.